# Telegram bot get 'chat not found' error when forwards messages in PHP

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I am getting errors like: **Bad Request: chat not found** when I want to forward a message from a group where the bot is an administrator.

Scenario:

- A public group called @PucciPruebas where the bot (@Comitentesbot) is an admin along with me (@fpucci).
- A test user (@fernandoPucci)
- I (@fpucci) and the test user (@fernandopucci) have previously written to the bot privately.

The idea is that when a member writes in the group, the bot forwards the message to me privately.

When I write in the group for example **This is a test message**, the bot receives this data:

```
Array ( 
    [update_id] => 768460433 
    [message] => Array ( 
        [message_id] => 8 
        [from] => Array (
            [id] => 1026410801 
            [is_bot] => 
            [first_name] => ??????????????????????¸ ??? 
            [last_name] => ??????????????? 
            [username] => FPucci 
            [language_code] => es 
        ) 
        [chat] => Array ( 
            [id] => -1001511892400 
            [title] => PucciPruebas 
            [username] => PucciPublico 
            [type] => supergroup 
        ) 
        [date] => 1653597954 
        [text] => This is a test message 
    )
)
```

The code in PHP is:

```
$tipo = $datain["message"]["chat"]["type"]; 
$chatid = $datain["message"]["chat"]["id"]; 
$msgid = $datain["message"]["message_id"]; 
$title = $datain["message"]["chat"]["title"];
if ("private"==$tipo || "PucciPruebas"==$title)
    Reenviar("@fpucci", $chatid, $msgid);

function Reenviar ($a_chat, $from_chat, $message){ 
    global $chatId, $comitentesapi; 
    $params=[ 
        'chat_id' => "$a_chat",
        'from_chat_id' => "$from_chat", 
        'message_id' => "$message", 
    ]; 
    $ch = curl_init("$comitentesapi/forwardMessage"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params)); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

So, what am I missing, forgetting, or doing wrong?

---------edit--------
I append after the **curl_close($ch)**, the following line as other way to send the message, and get the same result:

```
file_get_contents("$comitentesapi/forwardMessage?disable_notification=true&chat_id=$a_chat&from_chat_id=$from_chat&message_id=$message&parse_mode=HTML");
```

Comment: Have you started the bot?

Comment: Yes, As i say, bot users have previously written to the bot privately, starting it.

Comment: Also, if I write to the bot in private, I get the same error. Chat not found.

Comment: This is the URL to send the message:
https://api.telegram.org/bot1598380111:4445oISInixjqIl1v9edal_kyD8G9GqnJHM/forwardMessage?disable_notification=true&chat_id=@fpucci&from_chat_id=1026410801&message_id=12869&parse_mode=HTML

Comment: I just found out that the problem comes from the first parameter, $a_chat, the recipient of the forward. but I don't know what is wrong.